# On inactive logo gray and on click normal color and on change back to gray

Tags: html, jquery, css, wordpress

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdqPB.png)

On inactive logo gray and on click normal color and on change back to gray

Comment: First, don't (just) post a picture of your problem and expect us to guess what's going on. Further, adding "I need help" to the picture helps nobody; you posted a "question" (of sorts), we know you need help, and we're happy to do so, that's why we're here. What you need to do is read the guidance on "*[mcve]*" code, and "*[ask]*", and then edit your question to show your (relevant) code, explain what you expected that code to do, what it's not doing and what you want help to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to learn about CSS pseudo-classes and use `:active` and `:hover` states to achieve your goal. Start here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active